# Após cadastro, redirecionar para outro layout no Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Tenho um layout para a página inicial do meu projeto, com apenas um formulário de cadastro e mais nada. Após a pessoa se cadastrar, ela é redirecionada para uma outra página, completamente diferente da página inicial. Meu controller está assim:

```
if ($this->User->save($this->request->data){
   $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));
}
```

Criei outro controller chamado `UsersController` e um método chamado `index()`, e dentro dele coloquei assim:

```
function index(){
    $this->layout = 'user';
}
```

O cadastro ocorre normalmente, só que o layout não muda, fica na mesma tela inicial. Já tentei colocar esse código no `beforeFilter()` mas também não adiantou. Como posso fazer para isso funcionar?

Comment: Você tem os arquivos `app/View/Users/index.ctp` e `app/View/Layouts/user.ctp`? O que quer dizer com "fica na mesma tela inicial"? Não aparece a view do users/index?

Comment: Então, o Layouts/user.ctp eu tenho, o Users/index.ctp não
O que quero dizer e que após o submit, ele fica na mesma tela, não muda entende?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o problema, criei a pasta Users dentro da view com o arquivo index.ctp
Obrigado pela dica

Comment: Que bom que resolveu. Só acrescentando, a ideia do layout é ser a "casca" da view. O conteúdo em site deve estar na view (o index.ctp que estava faltando).

Comment: Valeu pela dica amigo, porém me surgiu uma outra dúvida.
Como eu faço para abrir uma sessão após esse usuário se cadastrar e ser redirecionado? Ou seja, proteger a página User no caso? Não sei se o Auth seria para isso ou teria que usar Session

Comment: O Auth já utiliza o Session internamente para isso. Mas se está tendo dificuldades, sugiro abrir uma nova pergunta específica sobre isso.

Comment: Ok amigo, obrigado, vou fazer isso